# Clip Start and Clip end not showing in blender 2.81 for sun light

Tags: lighting

I am doing lighting in eevee by watching a tutorial. So in tutorial it shows that clip start and clip end for shadows in object data properties but mine is not showing. If there is any other way to do it please help.
the above image is of my pc and the below one is from the tutorial.

[image: This is my interface]

[image: This is the Tutorial]

Answer (score 1):

Sun light shadow bounds are now [automatically calculated](https://developer.blender.org/T66745#856789), so manually adjusting clipping values is no longer necessary.

The properties have been removed and the UI adjusted accordingly.